# Cannot find a free socket for the debugger in eclipse oxygen with Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse

Everything was working fine but recently I am facing a strange issue in my laptop. My Eclipse debug is not working and getting error

> Cannot find a free socket for the debugger

I am logged in as Administrator.

My System Specification:

- Windows 8.1
- Java 8
- Eclipse Oxygen
- kaspersky Internet Security 2018

Tried below options by referring various sites.

- Disabled kaspersky Internet Security
- Disabled windows Firewall
- Moved Eclipse folder to C: drive
- Pointed Eclipse to older Java version i.e. 1.7

Still not able to fix the problem. I am totally blocked with this issue.

[image]

Comment: Run `netstat`..

Comment: Thanks a lot, now its working fine but it works only for few minutes and again same problem, then I need to re-run netstat command, could you please suggest any permanent fix...

Comment: Wait, what? Something is using up your ephemeral ports. Run `netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp` to see the number of ports that you can use. And use `netstat` to find out who is using up the ports.

Comment: I ran "netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp" and got below result like 
Start Port      : 49152
Number of Ports : 16384
and tried running again netstat then got some big list
One more issue today I found, even MySQL connection failing for port 3306 from JDBC code.
Is this all due to any malware problem?, please suggest.

Comment: Run `netstat -b` as administrator. This lists the programs that use the ports. Find the one that uses a lot of them....

Comment: I tried running netstat -b in admin cmd, in that chrome and dropbox was taking more ports, even after closing chrome and killing dropbox instance still when i run eclipse in debug mode still getting same error.

Comment: I tried even creating another windows account but still the same issue. Any idea, what else can be done...